# Making webservice up with WildFly 10

Tags: spring, cxf, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am facing a problem on making my webservice up on my WildFly 10. Can someone provide some light to this. I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener from [Module "org.apache.cxf.impl:main" from local module loader

I am using cxf-3.1.11 .

Comment: Is this a server or a client? There should be no need to use CXF directly. You only need to use the JDK based APIs.

Comment: This is a server. Am trying to make my webservices up in the server, it works fine if i use older jboss(jboss5 and jboss4). And my friend is able to make it up in wildfly 8 with cxf 2.7

Comment: Do you have a WSDL, or are you generating it from Java?

Comment: Am generating from java, In other jboss(jboss 5 or less) and when am using axis2 also , am able to generate wsdl by accessing the url itself(if i configure aar files and beans file correctly). But here the service endpoint itself is showing as no service available or the above exception is coming

Comment: Do you have external consumers of this service or do have control of all the clients?

Comment: this is consumed by external consumers mostly